# How to create a file with the names of cities and the state of the city from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmfilter

Is it posible to extract data from OpenStreetMap that only contains the name of a city and the name of the state from these city?

I want to build a CSV file, where each row contains "city;state". 
For example:

```
San Francisco;California
Annapolis;Marryland
....
```

At the moment I'm using osmfilter and osmconvert to create a file from all cities.

```
osmfilter file.o5m --keep="place=city or ( place=town and population>=1000 )" --drop-relations --drop-ways > cities.osm
osmconvert cities.osm --all-to-nodes --csv="name" --csv-headline > cities.csv
```

But how can I add the information about the state / country?

Comment: have you considered geonames.org instead

Comment: yes, but I want to receive the data from openstreetmap because I want to extend my file with other names later. For example: If the city is on an island, I want to add the name from the island in the third column.

Comment: Have you considered to use the famous overpass-api (or overpass-turbo.eu) for that query? Maybe you can try a query for each of the 50 states in the USA (via a batch, or a recursive command) where you extract objects with place=city or ( place=town and population>=1000)

Comment: Overpass looks nice. Is there a way to build the query that returns a specific language for the states name?